# After chaining in jQuery how to refer to the very first selected element again?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, chaining

Assume something like this:

```
$(#element).parent().parent().find().click().XXXrefer-my-first-selector-againXXX()
```

I know there is a way - after chaining - to reselect the first element again, but neither can I remember it, nor do I know for what keyword to search.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`end`](http://api.jquery.com/end):

> End the most recent filtering operation in the current chain and return the set of matched elements to its previous state.

In this case, as you have two `parent` and one `find`, you need three of them:

```
$("#element")
  .parent()
  .parent()
  .find(/*...arg here...*/)
  .click()
  .end()
  .end()
  .end()
  .doSomethingElseOnOriginalElement();
```

```js
$("#element")
  .parent()
  .parent()
  .find(".d")
  .click()
  .end()
  .end()
  .end()
  .append("<span>- and we're back</span>");
```

```html
<div class="a">a
  <div class="b">b
    <div class="c">c
      <div id="element">element</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="d">d</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But frankly in the code you've quoted, I'd just use a variable:

```
var elm = $("#element");
elm.parent().parent().find(/*...arg here...*/).click();
elm.doSomethingElseOnOriginalElement();
```

Comment: Thank you, T.J. - `end` was the function I could not remember, but of course a variable was the best solution.